# How to make a PyGTK widget respond quickly when the callback takes too long?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I do a time-consuming processing in the _init callback function. Therefore, at the GUI, when I activate the check-button, the program freezes, while the processing runs to completion, and then the check mark appears and execution resumes normally.

```
self.init = gtk.CheckButton("Init", False)
self.init.connect("toggled", self._init)

def _init(self, w):
....
```

How do I make the GUI more responsive while the processing takes place ?

And is there a way I can make the GUI change the state of the check-box right in the beginning and then enter the heavy loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several solutions:

1. Make the computation in a worker thread, which will send the result to the main thread. But don't change GUI items in the worker thread. Like most toolkits, GTK is not thread safe. I don't really like that one, as I don't really like threads, as they tend to make debugging harder...
2. Split the processing in an idle handle. When I say split, I really mean to split it in several steps that take much less time to compute. You should use an automaton with several states taking each much less time. Putting a big fat calculus in an idle handler is like calling sleep(5) in that handler: the GUI message pump would be blocked for 5 seconds, with no way to handle redrawing events... Here's an [example of lazy loading](http://web.archive.org/web/20080321054327/http://log.emmanuelebassi.net/documentation/lazy-loading/) data using this technique.
3. Force a call to the message pump on a regular basis using [gtk_main_iteration](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-General.html#gtk-events-pending).

The examples I gave you are in C, but the spirit is the same in python.

Comment: Thanks liberforce for the detailed answer. Method 3 was the quickest to implement. It does the job fine.

Answer (score -1):

In the handler, register the rest of the init as idle-handler and return. `gtk.idle_add` IIRC. That way it will run after the gui events are handled. Check documentation to see which value you need to return so the function is not started again.